# Project is targeting frameworks not installed or are included as part of future updates to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

I am attempting to convert the Microsoft.Health C# class library that is installed as part of the [HealthVault SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3418), using instructions provided [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/imilovanovic/archive/2012/08/31/vs2012---how-to-manually-convert-.net-class-library-to.aspx).  After following these instructions, I get the following error when attempting to load the project into Visual Studio 2013.

> "The project is targeting frameworks hat are either not installed or
>   are included as part of future updates to Visual Studio. See 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287985"

Visiting the link takes me to .NET SDKs and Downloads.  Once there, I have no clue on what needs to be done.

I do realize that one will have to leverage the [Portable Class Library Contrib](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/) project to fill in some missing bits, especially code related to System.Security.  This, I will deal with later.

Any one run into a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe so late but for those who have the same problem. 
I had the same error in a project which was working perfect before updating VS2013 and finally after 3 hours looking for the source of the error I found that the error is about `TargetFrameworkProfile`.

In my case I sloved it like so:

1. Right click in the unloaded project in your solution and click **Edit**.
2. Find the `TargetFrameworkProfile` tag and set it as below:

   ```
   <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile78</TargetFrameworkProfile>
   ```

Comment: Profile78 fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, this is because you need to specify the `TargetFrameworkVersion` and `TargetFrameworkProfile` properties in the project file.  Compare the .csproj you are trying to create to a newly created PCL project file, and make sure that everything that's not specific to your project matches.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and got it resolved by installing the latest Visual Studio Update